# Return value of system() function

Tags: c, child-process, libc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
printf("Hello World..\n");
system("ls");
}
```

Here...ON SUCCESSFUL execution system function returns the statys of "ls" command..and ON FAILURE it returns -1..

so can anyone help me to get this FAILURE condition for system function that gives return value as "-1"

Comment: Are you asking how to cause `system` to fail so that it returns `-1`? What do you want to do with the result?

Answer (score 4):

The `system` function returns `-1` if `system` itself fails, not if the command it invokes fails. For example, `system` returns `-1` if the `fork` call fails. This can happen if your system is very short on resources, such as memory, or if your system imposes a limit on the number of processes you can run.

If the command fails (for example if you call `system("false")`), the value returned by `system` isn't simply the return value of the command; it's the value returned by the `wait` system call; `man 2 wait` for more information. (This assumes a Unix-like system; the behavior of `system()` on other operating systems differs.)

Of course if you want to see the value returned by a call to `system`, you'll need to store that value in a variable:

```
int result = system("ls");
```

You should read the documentation for the `system` function.

If you're trying to cause `system` to fail and return `-1`, one way to do it is to use it to invoke your program recursively. This can consume a lot of memory, and may interfere with your system. Do this only if you're the only person using the system, and you don't mind possibly interfering with its operation.

(Incidentally, the definition for `main` should be `int main(void)`, not just `main()`, though that's not directly relevant. Prior 1999, omitting the return type would default to `int`; that's no longer permitted, but many compiler still support the old form. Empty parentheses do not specify the number of parameters; `(void)` explicitly says that there are no parameters, and is the preferred form.)

Comment: "wait system call" assuming you are on a posixized system (why?)

Comment: @n.m.: Good point. The OP is using gcc and the `ls` command, which makes it likely it's a Unix-like system, but I've updated my answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: @n.m.: Which is a Unix-like system.